# $.ajax POST not receiving data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If you wish to visit my [webpage](http://54.171.230.22/)

Login details that can be used are 
(case sensitive):

Username: stack

Password: stack

Click on yourhours tab.

My overall goal is to send all data from input boxes to a database. However currently I am just trying to get the interaction from the javascript and the PHP working. In the console I can see that the data variable has the value of "". I cannot see why this is happening.

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $startTime = $_POST["startTime"];
  echo $startTime;
?>
```

**HTML**

[http://pastebin.com/7p9NiV44](http://pastebin.com/MSCFd3pn)

Comment: you really need to post your full code here. Visiting your site won't do us much good, except maybe look at the html source. I for one won't be visiting the url. Look at your console and use error reporting.

Comment: Please show the form or at the least the markup for the element with `id` = `startTime` and also show how you trigger the function `d()`.

Comment: Not to mention that when that page changes it will render this question useless in the future

Comment: For starters what are you actually sending? If you see empty string in response then sounds like you are sending empty string

Comment: You are sending an object via POST. I believe this is considered JSON, what if you make data `"startTime=" + startTime` instead? Or do `$startTime = json_decode($_POST['startTime']);` on the server side.

Comment: I am just triggering the function by executing it in the console. There doesnt seem to be any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is working and is sending the value of the startDate input element to your sendHours.php. Your PHP-script is also correct.

By some reason your $_POST array isn't populated and it's not possible to come up with a solution based on your question alone. I would start by checking my php.ini, especially the setting `post_max_size`.

Also, you could try replacing your PHP-code with a simple `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` to verify that your setup is working to that extent at least.

Comment: What would i be looking for?

Comment: If the `post_max_size` directive is set to some invalid value or a smaller value than your postdata (highly unlikely) PHP will simply not populate `$_POST`. There is also a directive `enable_post_data_reading` that when set to false will make PHP ignore your postdata.

Comment: Well I just figured out that if I pass the variable totalHours to the php it returns that just fine.

Comment: At first what you were saying felt far fetched seeing that the POST method was working in one instance. But I decided to check it out because I had nothing to lose. Thank you so much man, I was about to give up on my project :)

Comment: My enable_post_data_reading was set to Off for some reason. I have not even touched PHP before so I have no idea why that happened.

Answer (score 2):

not a solution but add the error section to get a better idea of what is going on.

```
 function d(){
    var startTime = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
    console.log(startTime);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendHours.php",
        data: {startTime: startTime},
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }, 
        error: function(err, status) { console.log(err);}
    })
}
```

Comment: *"not a solution..."* - *lol* ok, well the OP's going to have to make the best of it then, *right?*. So... why the answer then? OP still didn't respond to [my comment up there...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418897/ajax-post-not-receiving-data#comment70043039_41418897).

Comment: I appreciate the help Bindrid.